# Grab first element from three arrays and put them inside its own array, then do the same for the second element and so forth in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three arrays

```
arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]

arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]

arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
```

and I want three new arrays to look like so

```
arr4 = ["a1", "b1", "c1"]

arr5 = ["a2", "b2", "c2"]

arr6 = ["a3", "b3", "c3"]
```

How can I accomplish getting these new arrays in JavaScript?

Comment: how do you think you'd do it? Take a guess - your participation is part of this experience

Comment: let combinedArray = [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3]

const res = combinedArray.map((x, i) => {
         return x[0]
      })

that gives me this ["a1", "b1", "c1"] 

but im having trouble wrapping my head around how to create new arrays for each of the element im indexing through

Comment: research matrix transposition algorithms

Answer (score 0):

You Can use two loop to do that but you will add all arrays in one array to do the loop and we extract new arrays in another array

Here is your code

```
let arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];
```

We add all arrays in one variable

```
let allArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
```

We make a array to give all new arrays in

```
let resultArr = [];
```

We make the first loop to loop in each array

```
for (let i = 0; i < allArr.length; i++) {
```

We make a array called res to make the new arrays

```
let res = [];
```

We make another loop on `allArr` Variable but for change we use a `foreach` loop

```
  allArr.forEach((arr) => {
    res.push(arr[i]);
  });
```

Then We add res after we make it to the `resultArr` Vairable

```
resultArr.push(res);
```

And We close out loop

```
}
```

Here is you code

```
let arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
  arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
  arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

let allArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
let resultArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allArr.length; i++) {
  let res = [];
  allArr.forEach((arr) => {
    res.push(arr[i]);
  });
  resultArr.push(res);
}
```

I add this loop to log the array in console only. To see that working live

```
resultArr.forEach((arr) => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```js
let arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
  arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
  arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

let allArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
let resultArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < allArr.length; i++) {
  let res = [];
  allArr.forEach((arr) => {
    res.push(arr[i]);
  });
  resultArr.push(res);
}
resultArr.forEach((arr) => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

I hope to be good in my explain :)

Comment: this works but what if i have 20+ elements? I am looking for what a loop solution would look like

Comment: @Akshay I Understand you. And i change my reponse

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way - put the source arrays in one variable, use the length of the shortest source array as the iterator length and create the new variables on the fly.

```js
let arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"]
let arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"]
let arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]

// just in case they're not all the same length, we'll use the shortest one as the iterator length

let ct = 0,
  st = 4,
  arrs = [arr1, arr2, arr3],
  len = Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length, arr3.length);
while (ct < len) {
  this[`arr${st+ct}`] = arrs.map(a => a[ct]);
  ct++;
}

console.log(arr5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let mixedArr = [arr1, arr2, arr3];
let res = [];
for (i=0;i<mixedArr.length;i++) {
    res.push(mixedArr.map(arr => arr[i]))
}
console.log(res)
```

And then you can just grab what you need from the finished array

Answer (score 0):

This may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// method to transpose the arrays
const transpose = arr => {
  // first create a placeholder "result" 2D array
  const result = [
    ...Array(Math.min(
      ...arr.map(a => a.length)
    ))
  ].map((_, i) => [
    ...Array(arr[i].length)
  ].map(x => ""));
  
  // now, traverse through input 2D array & 
  // populate "result" by transposing row & col
  arr.forEach((row, rIdx) => 
    row.forEach((elt, cIdx) => 
      result[cIdx][rIdx] = elt
    )
  )
  
  return result;
};

const arrayOfArrays = [
  ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
  ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
  ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
];

console.log(
  'test case 1: ',
  JSON.stringify(arrayOfArrays),
  '\nresult: ',
  JSON.stringify(transpose(arrayOfArrays))
);

// using with the context of the question

const arr1 = ["a1", "a2", "a3"];
const arr2 = ["b1", "b2", "b3"];
const arr3 = ["c1", "c2", "c3"];

console.log(
  'using arr1, 2, 3: \n',
  JSON.stringify({arr1, arr2, arr3}),
  '\nraw-result: ',
  JSON.stringify(transpose([arr1, arr2, arr3]))
);

// getting the result arrays separately
const [arr4, arr5, arr6] = transpose([arr1, arr2, arr3]);

console.log(
  'showing result arrays arr4, 5, 6: \n',
  JSON.stringify({arr4, arr5, arr6})
);

// Testing with "20" element arrays

const alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('');
const num = 20;
const twentyArr = [...Array(num).keys()].map(k => [...Array(num).keys()].map((_, i) => `${alph[k]}${i+1}`));

console.log(
  'Testing for twenty elements array: \n',
  JSON.stringify(twentyArr),
  '\nresult:\n',
  JSON.stringify(transpose(twentyArr))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments provided in the snippet above.

Comment: OP's comment to another answer: _but what if i have 20+ elements?_ has also been addressed in above answer. This answer is expected to work as long as number of elements in each array is consistent (so, 3, or 4, or 5, or even 20).